# User entering data into the form is delayed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an input field named name and age.
When I enter "J", the data will be "null", when I enter another character "o", it will receive "J". To appear complete "John" I need to enter a space behind "John_". So is there a way to enter that setState immediately receives it? Thank you very much

```
class RequestDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: this.requestList,
    };
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
  }

  requestList = {
    name: "",
    age: "",
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    let list = { ...this.state.list };
    list[name] = value;
    this.setState({ list })
  }
  async handleSubmit(event){
    //Send data in form to api
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <Input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInput} />
         <Input type="text" name="age" onChange={this.handleInput} />
         <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing, since in your handle submit you get complete values from the form

Comment: I have 2 input fields, name and age.
When I enter John at name and 23 at age, when I submitForm, data will be: "John" age: 2. When I add a space at age field like "23_", the  state gets the name: "John" age: "23"

Comment: How are you checking your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing the value props

```
   <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <Input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.list.name} onChange={this.handleInput} />
         <Input type="text" name="age" value={this.state.list.age} onChange={this.handleInput} />
         <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
      </Form>
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-worker-4ru4v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It does not work for me. When I enter John at name and 23 at age, when I submitForm, data will be: "John" age: 2. When I add a space at age field like "23_", the state gets the name: "John" age: "23". I'm thinking the error in "state"

Comment: u see the codesandbox? does codesandbox work for u? Wait,.. are you talking about onChange or onSubmit??

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-worker-4ru4v?file=/src/App.js it's working even for onSubmit

Comment: I saw your codesanbox. Your code run. But in my question I has a sentence: "So is there a way to enter that setState immediately receives it?" When I fix my code like your code I see the value is changed imediately but when I submit it occur error

Comment: There is a handleSubmit, and you need to add this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this).

Comment: Yeah, I added handleSubmit in constructor. Your code: "value={this.state.list.....}" does not run for me because I can not see what character I input so I change the value to defaultValue and it work

Comment: default value only works on the first load though.